# php redirect with custom user roles set and working but redirect not working for when users are logged in

Tags: php

I have created code to add custom user rules. It works. However when I try to tie in the code for redirecting an already logged in user based on one test role, then it doesn't work. What am I missing in this in order to have it redirect, based on a user's role. Here is the code:

```
add_action('init', 'cloneRoleCompany');
function cloneRoleCompany(){
    global $wp_roles;
    if ( ! isset( $wp_roles ) )
        $wp_roles = new WP_Roles();

    $adm = $wp_roles->get_role('subscriber');
    //Adding a 'new_role' with all admin caps
    $wp_roles->add_role('company-admin', 'Company Admin', $adm->capabilities);
    $wp_roles->add_role('company', 'Company', $adm->capabilities);
    $wp_roles->add_role('user', 'User', $adm->capabilities);
}
function redirect_from_front_page() {
    $redirect_url  = '/user-dashboard';
    $expected_role = 'user';

    if( is_front_page() ) {
        return;
    }

    if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        return;
    }
    

    $user  = wp_get_current_user();
    $roles = $user->roles;
    

    if ( in_array( $expected_role, $roles ) ) {
        wp_safe_redirect( $redirect_url );
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: You’re only passing by a path. Does it work if you pass a full URL?

Comment: Thanks. It does not make a difference

Comment: Try changing `if( is_user_logged_in() )` to  `if(  ! is_user_logged_in()  )`

Comment: that would redirect only if a user is not logged in however.

Comment: As shane suggests, the guard conditions in this function cause it exit early prior to the role check/redirect if the user is on the front page or if they are logged in. In short, your role check/redirect execution logic is only executing for logged-out visitors on any page which isn't the front page, assuming `redirect_from_front_page()` is called/hooked to action which fires on each page load.

Comment: when and where is `redirect_from_front_page` called? Shane is right, right now it only runs for logged out users because if you're logged in it returns early. You can test this by putting a `wp_die('check' );` just before the return in that `if` statement, @shanebp you should leave it as an answer rather than a comment

Answer (score 1):

If the user is logged-in, the function returns *before* the redirect code lower in the function.

```
if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    return;
}
```

Since you want the redirect code to run only if the user is logged in, try this:

```
if( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
    return;
}
```

Comment: thanks but this would make it where the user is not logged in with the ```!```

Comment: Try it.  Or don't. But seems you don't understand what `is_user_logged_in()` returns.

Comment: ```is_user_logged_in()``` according to the docs is self explanatory. Adding the ```!```` in front changes it to look to see if the user is not logged in. I am not wanting to redirect if the user is not logged in.